# How to apply \setbeamertemplate inside a beamertemplate

Tags: beamer

I am playing with Beamer templates and I am puzzled by something.
If I set beamer templates in a bracket environment, I do not get the same result than if I set these in another beamer template and use it inside the frame.

Here is a MWE of what I would like to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{metropolis}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{section perso}{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \fill[color=gray]  (1.,-1.) rectangle (15.,-8.);% 
    }%
}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{section perso}[1][]{\insertframetitle}

\defbeamertemplate*{toc page}{perso}[1][]
{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[section perso]%
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[section perso]%
   \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=gray}%
    \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=white}%
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=white}%
    \setbeamercolor{subsubsection in toc}{fg=white}%
}


\begin{document} %

   \begin{frame}{first}
      tata
   \end{frame}

{
   %% WORKING
    % \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[section perso]
    % \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[section perso]
   % \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=gray}
    % \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=white}
    % \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=white}
    % \setbeamercolor{subsubsection in toc}{fg=white}

    % \setbeamertemplate{toc page}[perso] % NOT WORKING
    % \setbeamertemplate*{toc page}[perso] % NOT WORKING
    \begin{frame}{TOC}
        \usebeamertemplate{toc page}%[perso] % NOT WORKING
      % \usebeamertemplate*{toc page}%[perso] % NOT WORKING
      % \usebeamertemplate**{toc page}%[perso] % NOT WORKING
      % \usebeamertemplate***{toc page}%[perso] % NOT WORKING
      % \setbeamertemplate{toc page}[perso] % NOT WORKING
        % \setbeamertemplate*{toc page}[perso] % NOT WORKING
      \begin{columns}
        \column{0.30\textwidth}
        \column{0.70\textwidth}
            test
            \tableofcontents
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{title}
        toto
    \end{frame}
} 
 
\section{Chapiter}
\subsection{sub sec}

\end{document}
```

So my question is how to set a beamer template that calls other beamer templates for only some slides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invent a new template (like `toc page`), which is not used by beamer, just setting it is not enough, you'll also have to actually use the template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{section perso}{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \fill[color=gray]  (1.,-1.) rectangle (15.,-8.);% 
    }%
}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{section perso}[1][]{\insertframetitle}

\defbeamertemplate*{toc page}{perso}[1][]
{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[section perso]%
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[section perso]%
   \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=gray}%
    \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=white}%
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=white}%
    \setbeamercolor{subsubsection in toc}{fg=white}%
}

\begin{document} %

   \begin{frame}{first}
      tata
   \end{frame}

{
     \setbeamertemplate{toc page}[perso] 
     \usebeamertemplate{toc page}
    \begin{frame}{TOC}
      \begin{columns}
        \column{0.30\textwidth}
        \column{0.70\textwidth}
            test
            \tableofcontents
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{title}
        toto
    \end{frame}
} 
 
\section{Chapiter}
\subsection{sub sec}

\end{document}
```

[image]